# Index Match ( keeping index-matched information updated)

Tags: excel

So I have a index match formula like this =INDEX([Employee_detail.xls]Current!$B:$B,MATCH(H3,[Employee_detail.xls]Current!$C:$C,0))

I'm linking it to other workbook, that is the employee detail, so that whenever i type in the Employee ID I don't need to key in the rest of the information like position,name. But the problem is when the information in the employee detail (the other workbook) is updated, the information in my current worksheet is not updated, even after i re-insert the Employee ID manually.

How to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance for your patience!

Comment: have you tried to update links?  On the **Data** tab of the ribbon, in the **Connections** group, click the **Edit Links** button.

Comment: I tried using your suggestion, but the source couldn't be found. I noticed that my file's name is "Employee Detail", but in the formula i typed "Employee_Detail", and maybe due to this mistake, the source is not found. So i changed the formula to =INDEX('Z:\Admin\Admin\Employee Details\[Employee Detail.xls]Current'!$B:$B,MATCH(H3,'Z:\Admin\Admin\Employee Details\[Employee Detail.xls]Current'!$C:$C,0)). But when I updated the Employee file, the formula shows "ref!" error.. What should I do?

Comment: I would suggest going to the data tab and creating a connection to the workbook either by inserting the data from `[Employee_detail.xls]Current!$B:$B` and `[Employee_detail.xls]Current!$C:$C` in another sheet and hiding it or just creating the connection that you are referencing. You can then use Data > Update Connections to pull through up to date information or if you don't mind having a macro enabled workbook use could create a simple macro for `Workbook.RefreshAll` to run on Spreadsheet open or save (maybe even inserting it as a button).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have managed get the correct formula. The problem lies within the name of the file name "employee detail". Thank you for the help and I appreciate that! :)